# How to close secondary view in uwp

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml

I'm building an UWP app that spawn second view besides the main view.

I want to close the second view from the main view.
I already try to google it, but most of it only show me how to spawn but not to close.

Below is the code block I use to open a new view, and at its bottom is how I try to close the newly created view that always ends up fail.

```
    public async void OpenNew(Type type, string title, string uniqueId)
    {
        CoreApplicationView newView = null;
        if (!IsExists(uniqueId))
        {
            newView = CoreApplication.CreateNewView();

            int newViewId = 0;
            await newView.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                Frame frame = new Frame();
                Window.Current.Content = frame;
                Window.Current.Activate();
                frame.Navigate(type);

                newViewId = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Id;
                ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Title = title;
                ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Consolidated += OnConsolidated;
            });

            await ApplicationViewSwitcher.TryShowAsStandaloneAsync(newViewId);
            _uniqueIds.Add(uniqueId, newViewId);
        }

        // Below code testing on how I try to close newly spawned view but always throw error
        await Task.Delay(5000).ContinueWith(async _ =>
        {
            await Window.Current.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                newView.CoreWindow.Close();
            });
        });
    }
```

This code always throws

```
Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException'
```

Any link or tutorial on how to do it?

Comment: Please provide some more details. Best would be some code. What container control do you use? What do you mean by closing? Hiding completely? What do you expect to happen with the space when your secondary view is closed?

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: At which line is the exception raised?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvm, guys I got the answer. Below is my changes on the part where I try to close the 2nd view from the above code:

```
await Task.Delay(5000).ContinueWith(async _ =>
{
    await newView.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Close();
    });
});
```